# Can't connect mobile hotspot on VOID linux

Tags: linux, wifi, wifi-hotspot, void-linux

I installed the VOID 32 BIT XFCE
and couldn't connect to SOME mobilephone hotspots (I tested 3, one works just fine, 1 connects and I can ping websites but the moment I use xbps or the web I get no connection(wifi still connected) and pinging again gives error in name resolution, And the third one doesn't connect at all with error MSG saying wifi network not found)

What I have tried so far.
Updating the system
Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 to /etc/resolv.conf.
Installing dnsmasq package.
Restarting NetworkManager
Since I can connect to 1 hotspot I don't think it's hardware/driver issue(and am honestly at loss as to what to do next
Do tell if I need to add additional details

Any help is much appreciated